# engine replacement wont start

Tags: engine, ford, diesel, focus

can anyone help please changed engine on a 59 reg focus 1.8tdci could not find a good one anywhere near so ive got an 08 tdci as replacement same engine code kkda noticed while swapping the 08 has a sensor under manifold at the back the 59 does not engine started but would not rev now wont start just turns over someone says pump has to be recoded but ive since found out this sensor is a knock sensor would this be problem ive no wire on original harness to plug into it so left it hanging can someone please tell me if this is the problem thx

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the older engine didn't have a knock sensor, this wouldn't be a problem. If you were going the other way, where the computer needed the knock sensor, then there would be an issue. Have you checked it for codes?

Comment: no engine codes coming up been told pump needs coding but forums say it doesnt, injectors may need coding havent changed them for originals do you think they need changing for originals

Comment: Non-Brit readers may not know that a UK '59 reg' means a vehicle registered between September 2009 and March 2010.